# How to make a billboard background transparent

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl

I'm following tutorial: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial27/tutorial27.html

It works perfect! But when I try to change the object texture, background is white, not transparent. Firstly I thought that the trouble is with image, but another images is like from tutrorail.

So, how I can make object background transparent?
[My modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHPOC.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the fragment shader:

```
if (FragColor.r == 0 && FragColor.g == 0 && FragColor.b == 0) {
    discard;
}
```

Pixels that are completely black are discarded (not drawn). Make sure your image has pitch black color where you don't want pixels to be drawn, or rewrite the shader to fit your needs.